# This type of page is not served error on asp.net Web Pages with extension.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I've got a classic .asp web site that I'm trying to convert to Web Pages with Razor. I've created a template Razor web site with Visual Studio. I haven't done any other customizations yet. I can view the page fine on my local machine by hitting http://localhost:50910/Default.cshtml. But when I copy over the files to the hosting webserver I get this error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

This type of page is not served.

Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /RAZOR/Default.cshtml

I believe I have all the .dll files needed. What am I missing? Just going to /RAZOR/Default or /RAZOR/Index produces this error: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

As this is a test site the RAZOR folder is a subfolder of the wwwroot folder which already contains the old working .asp site, if that makes a difference.

Comment: <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" /> In your config?

Comment: I added :

<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings

but it did not do anything. Still does not serve the pages.